# Rails Production Logs in Google App Engine

Tags: ruby-on-rails, google-app-engine, logging

I have recently deployed my Rails application to GAE. However it throws up an error, as a result of which i need to check the log files to find out what's happening. Normally i used to access the logs/production.log to see what went wrong. How can I access logs/production.log in this case?

I have checked the logs provided by Stackdriver logging, but they are mostly nginx and build logs, and i can't find the production.log file.

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out. You have to enable debug on your instances, and then ssh into your instances. Following which, you have to access the docker container running your app.

https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/ruby/debugging-an-instance